# Redundant arguments in Workbook_SheetSelectionChange?

Tags: vba, excel, arguments, selection

In

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

is `Sh` redundant?

I guess that we can **always** obtain a reference to a (copy of?) `Sh`, with `Target.Parent`.
Is this correct?
Is there any rationale or use for that argument, other than saving the user from creating such variable?

Comment: Yes you could obtain it via parent, so in theory it is redudant, but that is indirect and less efficient. taking that logic further, sheet would be removed from the VBA object model altogther.

Comment: You could obtain `Target` just by looking at `Selection` so it could also be seen as redundant

Comment: I'm going to say "yes," it's redundant. But I'm glad it's available. BTW, I recently noticed that there is a `Range.Worksheet` property.

Comment: @barrowc - You are probably correct. I cannot think of any single exception to your statement. I also found that redundancy "amusing".

Comment: @brettdj - I do not understand where would efficiency be degraded. And I also do not understand your last sentence. I apologize for my ignorance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarizing the comments received:

**YES**, `Sh` is redundant, it can be obtained with `Target.Parent` or `Selection.Parent`.
`Target` is also redundant, it can be obtained with `Selection`.

A similar comment applies to a few other events.